# How can I modifiy the positions of the text and logo on RMarkdown title slide

Tags: css, r, r-markdown, pandoc, xaringan

**Because of the picture I have at the bottom of my title slide, I want to**:

- move all `title`, `subtitle` and `author` up from their center positions.
- remove the `Rlogo` in the title slide only (don't really know how to do it). I could only remove slide number for now using `.title-slide .remark-slide-number { display: none; }`.

Any suggestion is appreciated! Thanks!

Here is my reproducible example:

**tweaks.css file**

```
/* for logo and slide number in the footer */
.remark-slide-content:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 15px;
    right:   8px;
    height: 40px;
    width: 120px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    background-image: url("Rlogo.png");
}

/* for background image in title slide */
.title-slide {
  background-image: url("slideMasterSample.png");
  background-size: cover;
}

.title-slide h1 {
  color: #F7F8FA;
  margin-top: -170px;
}

.title-slide h2, .title-slide h3 {
  color: #e7e8e2; 
  line-height: 1.0em;
  margin-top: -75px;
}

.title-slide .remark-slide-number {
  display: none;
}
```

**1st attempt**: modified `margin-top` in `tweaks.css` file as mentioned in [`xaringan` wiki](https://github.com/yihui/xaringan/wiki/Title-slide)

```
---
title: "Presentation Ninja"
subtitle: "xaringan"
author: "Author"
output:
  xaringan::moon_reader:
    lib_dir: libs
    css: ["default", "tweaks.css"]
    nature:
      highlightStyle: github
      highlightLines: true
      countIncrementalSlides: false
---
```

**Result 1**:

[image: Result 1]

**2nd attempt**: added `<br>` to the `title` to manually push it up but then the `subtitle` and `author` were also pushed down. Adding `<br>` to `subtitle` and `author` did not help either.

```
---
title: "Presentation Ninja<br><br><br><br><br><br>"
subtitle: "xaringan"
author: "Author"
output:
  xaringan::moon_reader:
    lib_dir: libs
    css: ["default", "tweaks.css"]
    nature:
      highlightStyle: github
      highlightLines: true
      countIncrementalSlides: false
---
```

**Result 2**:

[image: Result 2]

**Photos used**

[image: slideMasterSample.png]
[image: Rlogo.png]

Comment: try using chrome or firefox developer tools to edit the CSS on the fly...

Comment: Why didn't you keep editing the css until you got what you wanted?

Comment: @mb21: didn't know that I can do that. Thanks!

Comment: You didn't show any examples of that that I see.  What values for the margins did you try? What values for sub title? Also did you set padding?

Comment: Just look at what you copy and pasted ` background-image: url("Rlogo.png");`  If you don't want the logo make that empty or put in what you do want.  Read what is there, replace or change what you want to change.  There's no magic, just step by step read and modify, refresh.

Comment: @Elin: Thanks! I was very new to `CSS`. The reason I put `background-image: url("Rlogo.png");` was because I want that logo to be on every slide except the title slide. I was wondering if there is an option to remove it from the title slide only.
I also tried reducing `padding-top` and `border-top` but they did nothing to the position of the text.

Comment: Oh I see. Yes you can do complex things like that in css for example by applying a certain class to the title page that overrides the default background-image.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Using `seal: false` you can create a title slide that is independent from the YAML header. It often simplifies slide creation imo.

For the R logo across all slides but the title slide, create a custom div and set it as a `layout`.

[image][image]

CSS:

```
.title-slide {
  background-image: url("slideMasterSample.png");
  background-size: cover;
}
.title-slide h1, h2, h3 {
  text-align: center;
  color: #F7F8FA;
}

.title-slide .remark-slide-number {
  display: none;
}

div.my-footer {
content: "";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 15px;
    right:   8px;
    height: 40px;
    width: 120px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    background-image: url("Rlogo.png");
}
```

Rmd:

````
---
title: "Presentation Ninja"
subtitle: "xaringan"
author: "Author"
output:
  xaringan::moon_reader:
    lib_dir: libs
    css: ["tweaks.css", "default"]
    nature:
      highlightStyle: github
      highlightLines: true
      countIncrementalSlides: false
    seal: false
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
options(htmltools.dir.version = FALSE)
```

class: title-slide   

# Header 1

## Header 2  

### Header 3 

---

layout: true

<div class="my-footer"></div>       

---

# new slide 1

---

# new slide 2
````